# How to change state on multiple elements in React during onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the individual font awesome icon (1 of 6 icons) it changes color from gray to orange like it should. I would also like to make sure only one of the font awesome icons can be orange at a time. So if I click on another icon the one that was previously orange is now gray and the one I just clicked is orange. I have been struggling to get this going any tips will be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
export default function FontAwesomeIcons(props) {

  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

  const styles = {
    display: "inline-flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: "10px",
    color: color ? "orange" : "gray",
    cursor: "pointer"
  };

  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      onClick={() => setColor(!color)}
      style={styles}
      icon={props.name}
      size='2x'
    />
  );
}
```

It works like I described above but not like I would like.

Comment: Any luck on integrating a solution Keith?

Comment: I was out of service range yesterday, but your solution was spot on, thank you! Re-rendering all of the icons on every click and checking their state was something I didn't try, thanks again.

Comment: Hi Keith, just wondering why you would unaccept my answer which you confirmed was working perfectly fine for you, then accept one that doesn't really give you an answer?

Comment: Hi Christopher, It somehow unchecked your answer and I must have mistakenly checked the wrong one on my mobile. I am back at a computer now so problem is solved. Sorry about that.

Comment: hahah no worries friend. I was concerned that my answer was no longer working for you :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. The problem is that all the `FontAwesomeIcons` share the same `styles` object. So if color is `true`, then all icons become orange.

What you should do is move each `FontAwesomeIcon` into its own component, that way it can manage its own color `state` and style-object.

Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-frog-scci2

Let's consider this example:

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import FontAwesomeIcons from "./FontAwesomeIcons";
import { faCoffee, faUser, faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
const icons = [faCoffee, faUser, faTrash];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Choose Food</h4>
      <FontAwesomeIcons icons={icons} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

In the higher most component, we import the font-awesome icons we want to use and put them in an array called icons.

We pass those icons to our Child-component, FontAwesomeIcons which accepts that array as a property.

### FontAwesomeIcons.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MyIcon from "./MyIcon";
const FontAwesomeIcons = props => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState({});

  const createIcons = () => {
    const { icons } = props;
    return icons.map((icon, iconIndex) => {
      return (
        <MyIcon
          thisIcon={icon}
          selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
          iconIndex={iconIndex}
          setSelectedIndex={setSelectedIndex}
          size="2x"
        />
      );
    });
  };
  return createIcons();
};

export default FontAwesomeIcons;
```

In `FontAwesomeIcons`, we take that `icons` prop, and `iterate` over it to create a collection of icons. Instead of directly using the `FontAwesomeIcon` component provided by font-awesome, we will pass each `icon` in the array to a new instance of our own `MyIcon` component.

Additionally, we will keep track of a `selectedIndex` state, to determine which icon was clicked. `SelectedIndex` and its updater-function get passed down as props to `MyIcon` as well, which will be crucial for updating the style object.

### MyIcon.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const MyIcon = props => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.selectedIndex === props.iconIndex) {
      setColor(true);
    } else {
      setColor(false);
    }
  }, [props.selectedIndex]);

  const styles = {
    display: "inline-flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: "10px",
    color: color ? "orange" : "gray",
    cursor: "pointer"
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        onClick={() => props.setSelectedIndex(props.iconIndex)}
        style={styles}
        icon={props.thisIcon}
        size="2x"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyIcon;
```

Finally, in our custom `MyIcon` component, we will render`FontAwesomeIcon` using the icon that was passed via props. Note that each MyIcon component manages its own `color state` and styles object.

In the `FontAwesomeIcon` definition, for its `onClick()` we execute the state-updating function that was passed as a prop (props.setSelectedIndex) and we give it the icon-index belonging to this `MyIcon` component. That updates the selected-state of the parent, and that value gets passed back down to `MyIcon` for our evaluation.

So when you click on coffee-icon, you turn `selectedIndex` into the index of the icon belonging to the initial array, which is now readable in `MyIcon`. All instances of the MyIcon object re-renders and in each one, we check to see if `selected` object matches its own icon-index. If it does, we change the `color-state` to `true` (orange), if not, we change it to `false` (grey).

In summary, whenever you have components that are dependent on a common value, you should consider creating an intermediary state to help manage their functionality. That is the Parent-Child component relationship in a nut-shell.

Comment: This works perfectly and helped me understand a little more about Parent-Child component relationship, thank you!

Comment: @Keitharuni you're very welcome! I'm glad this was able to help you. Please remember to upvote and mark this answer as the solution (green) check-mark. Also feel free to let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Given the snippet you have provided it looks to me like  `FontAwesomeIcons` is a child component of some parent component.  Without being able to see the parent component, I will have to assume that you are rendering each component separately.  Because of this, each component is currently running independently of one another.

For the components to know when one component is orange would mean you would need to share the same data with each child component.  Two ways come to mind.

1) You can use redux. A bit bulky for what you are trying to do, but it will work.

2) You pass through a function from the parent that controls the state of the color of the button.  Add some logic in the parent, and you will gain more control over your button layout.

For instance in your parent component:

```
...
render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <FontAwesomeIcons onClick(() => {make magic})/>
     <FontAwesomeIcons onClick(() => {make magic})/>
      ...
   </div>
 )
}
```

This is of course not the best way to create multiple icons, but it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one common(Reusable) component of the fontawesome icon and you can use it n number of time wherever you want,
Check this out [demo](http://CHeck%20this%20out%20[enter%20link%20description%20here][1])

Answer (score 0):

You can use a toggle function that uses the previous state and then you can call the function on click event that'll do the job. Don't forget to pass the color codes.